# What does the "DS" in "DS-..." US visa application forms stand for?

Tags: visas, usa

Possibly a question for the meta section, but I was wondering what `DS` in `DS-160` or in `DS-2019` actually stands for?

-- just asking out of curiosity!

Comment: It's part of an identifying code, and does not *need* to stand for anything. It may have been based on something originally, but that meaning is not necessarily relevant any more (consider the *F/A* in the *F/A-18* jet, or the *AT&T* in AT&T Corporation).

Comment: @choster it may not *need* to stand for anything, but it *does.*  Even the question "what does AT&T stand for" has a meaningful answer, even if the official name of the corporation is just "AT&T Inc." or whatever it is.

Comment: @phoog "Department of State" is probably where the designation originated, but the Department of State also has various forms not prefixed as *DS* (e.g. [JF-57](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/jf57_pd.PDF)), and there is no guarantee that some form out among the probably tens of thousands of U.S. government forms is prefixed *DS* but not from the State Department. The OP did not indicate any background reasoning as to what real-world problem this relates to, so I am simply giving a warning not to read too much into it.

Comment: @choster, indeed, I should have mentioned that I am just asking out of curiosity!

Comment: @choster There's only [three prefixes](https://eforms.state.gov/). SF = standard form, used by the entire Federal Government. I am guessing JF = Joint Form, because they're all foreign employee evals and they are shared with a number of other agencies, like USAID.

Comment: @phoog In case you're curious, it's the [American Telegraph and Telephone Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T_Corporation) which came along from the Bell Telephone company. There's some very interesting pieces of history in the company, especially on the AT&T Tech Channel on YouTube.

Comment: This is a question about travel, not about the Travel SE, so putting this here rather than Meta is indeed the correct place.  Questions about general terminology from the subject matter belong in the main SE. Only if the general terminology is from the SE itself (e.g. "mod", "VTC") does it belong on Meta.

Comment: @AustinBurk That's kind of my point. The current company known as AT&T is different from the former company known as American Telephone and Telegraph (in fact, it began as a subsidiary of it). For the current company, AT&T has always been the full name, and has *never officially stood for anything*, and it would be inaccurate to call it American Telephone & Telegraph. Plenty of other former initialisms have been declared to stand for nothing, like BP, CBS, or FFA, and others have never been abbreviations, like CTV or HEB.

Comment: @choster "F/A" means "Fighter/Attack".

Comment: @ronjohn Again, as goes to my point, it doesn't. A fighter-attack aircraft would be designed FA, not F/A. The latter designation is a legacy of its development, which originally called for two variants based on the same airframe.

Comment: boy that escalated quickly...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

DS in DS-160 stands for [Department of State](https://www.uscis.gov/non-uscis-forms)

Comment: Nice! That's what I figured too by [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=ds+abbreviation+immigration) and finding a [random site](https://www.allacronyms.com/_government/DS/Immigration) with the answer but couldn't find an official source.